# Javascript function variable passing Uncaught ReferenceError: element is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onblur

Tags: javascript

So im just writing a script with simple Cart in JS.
Code below is inside a function which is running when Modal Opens.
Everything shows fine but im running inside input onblur function policzKoszt() and im passing variable from localStorage in a loop to find in next function and add QUANTITY to a localstorage field when i changed value of quantity in input.

```
function Koszyk(){

let cartProducts = localStorage.getItem("cartProducts");
//let total_price = policzKosztCalkowity();
cartProducts = JSON.parse(cartProducts);
let modal = document.querySelector(".modal-body-row");
if(modal.innerHTML.trim()!=""){
    modal.innerHTML="";
}
if(cartProducts){
modal.innerHTML="";
modal.innerHTML+='<div class="col-sm-3 nazwa font-weight-bold">Nazwa</div><div class="col-sm-3 cena font-weight-bold">Cena</div><div class="col-sm-3 liczba_sztuk font-weight-bold">Ilość</div><div class="col-sm-3 liczba_sztuk font-weight-bold">Cena całkowita</div>';
if(cartProducts && modal){
    cartProducts.forEach(function (Produkt){
        modal.innerHTML+='<div class="col-sm-3 nazwa">'
        +Produkt.nazwa+'</div><div class="col-sm-3 cena">'
        +Produkt.brutto+'</div><div class="col-sm-3 liczba_sztuk"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="input-modal-ilosc" onblur="policzKoszt('+Produkt.nazwa+');Koszyk();" placeholder="ilosc" value='
        +Produkt.ilosc+'></div><div class="col-sm-3 cena-total">'
        +Produkt.brutto*Produkt.ilosc+'</div>';
    });
    modal.innerHTML+='<div class="col-md-3 ml-auto mt-5"><b>Cena za zamówienie:</b> Nic </div>';
}
}else{
    modal.innerHTML="";
}
```

}

```
function policzKoszt(nazwa){
var ilosc_input = document.getElementById("input-modal-ilosc");
if(ilosc_input!=null){
    ilosc_input=ilosc_input.value;
}
let cartProducts = localStorage.getItem("cartProducts");
cartProducts = JSON.parse(cartProducts);

cartProducts.forEach(function (Produkt){
    if(Produkt.nazwa==nazwa){
        Produkt.ilosc=ilosc_input;
    }
})
cartProducts = JSON.stringify(cartProducts);
localStorage.setItem("cartProducts",cartProducts);}
```

But it shows when onblur function runs an error:
index.html:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: nazwa is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onblur
and its returning this:
policzKoszt(nazwa);Koszyk();

where nazwa is result from passing Produkt.nazwa
But when i use policzKoszt("nazwa") (adding in console in chrome). It runs perfectly and changes value of quantity in localStorage.

I have no idea where is my error in this script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

policzKoszt(\''+Produkt.nazwa+'\') is solving the problem